# Usage singular vs plural for "in their hands" and "on their face"

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, grammatical-number, agreement

Considering that Sam and his brother are waiting together for a movie to start, and each of them has a sugar candy in their hand, and each of them smiles… what will be the most grammatically correct way to say:

- Sam and his brother used to wait with **a sugar candy** in **their hand** and **a smile** **on their face**.
- Sam and his brother used to wait with **sugar candies** in **their hands** and **a smile** on **their face**.
- Sam and his brother used to wait with **sugar candies** **in their hands** and **smiles** **on their face**.
- Sam and his brother used to wait with **sugar candies** **in their hands** and **smiles** on **their faces**.

Tnx!

Answer (score 1):

The fact that they are both male makes it simpler.

Barring context that hasn't been provided, I would phrase it in the following way:

> Sam and his brother used to wait, each with a sugar candy in his hand and a smile on his face.

---

From a comment, I was asked what if it were a brother and sister.

If we don't specify that each has *a* candy in *one* hand (which the first sentence in the question seems to imply), then the form of the fourth sentence in the question will work:

> Sam and his sister used to wait with sugar candies in their hands and smiles on their faces.

---

If the singular gender-neutral third person is allowed, then the following can be used:

> Sam and his sister used to wait, each with a sugar candy in hand and a smile on their face.

Note that we can say "in hand" rather than "in *a* hand" because there is only a single sugar candy, so it would be held in just one hand.

This, however, is awkward. The use of *their face* doesn't sound entirely natural.

---

If we specify one candy and one hand and the singular gender-neutral third person is *not* allowed, the sentence can be easily reworded if *face* is dropped:

> Sam and his sister used to wait, each with a sugar candy in hand and a smile.

---

Finally, the sentence can be extended so as not to drop any element:

> Sam and his sister used to wait, each with a sugar candy in hand and both with smiles on their faces.

Comment: Thanks ;-) and what if Sam was waiting with his sister?
"Sam and his sister used to wait with a sugar candy in their hand and a smile on their face." - can this one work? Tnx!

Comment: @Tommy I have expanded my answer to include several different possibilities. The main point is that if you refer to a single person, you use singular nouns; if you refer to multiple people, you use plural nouns.

Comment: Great ;-) Many thanks Jason Bassford! I was wondering, what if "each" is dropped in the below option -- won't it still be assumed?
Instead of ***
"Sam and his sister used to wait, EACH with a sugar candy in hand and a smile on their face." ***
*** this option:
"Sam and his sister used to wait with a sugar candy in hand and a smile on their face."

Comment: @ommy It would likely be understood, but it would be ambiguous and awkward. In *whose* hand? And the use of *their face* makes it sound like they share a face.

Comment: Tnx @Jason Bassford, you are the best ;-)