# Put smiles on their face or their faces? which is correct?

Tags: grammatical-number

Suppose that I am talking to my friend about how to cheer up children, so which is correct?

When I think a bit more, both are correct: on their face means I am talking about it generally, in 'on their faces' I mean I am talking over children in front of me. Any suggestions?

> a) Seeing their best friends would put smiles on their face.
>
> b) Seeing their best friends would put smiles on their faces.

Comment: Please include your research!

Comment: I just thought about it, so it is not? Am I wrong in this thinking?

Comment: In that sense, each person put smiles (general here) on their or her/his face, so I thought they put smiles on their face if they see something interesting. But If I am surrounded by children, they put smiles..then I cannot say their face because I am seeing their faces.. Does it make sense? or Am I wrong?

Comment: Your theory is interesting but I don't think the fact that you can see the faces is relevant. Similar questions have been asked here https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/301625/theyre-using-a-cell-phone-vs-theyre-using-cell-phones and here https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/471314/usage-singular-vs-plural-for-in-their-hands-and-on-their-face?rq=1. You may find the answers helpful.

Comment: How many people are you talking about? Is *their* being used as the gender-neutral third-party singular pronoun? Or is it talking about multiple people? Is it a single face or multiple faces? If multiple people, do they share a single face?

Comment: Many thanks all. Using their face is very unusual, actually incorrect ^^.